# Application stops on debug

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every time I debug my project, my device showing dialog that my application has stopped. Here's my code. I don't know whats wrong with my code.

```
public class Nasabah extends Activity {
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> contactList;
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nasabah);

    final ListView listNasabah = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNasabah);

    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting...");
    db.addContact(new Contact("Jose Mourinho", "087888888888", "1088994444"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Didier Drogba", "0878555555555", "1088996666"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Eden Hazard", "0878511111111", "1088995555"));

    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts...");
    List<Contact> contact = db.getAllContacts();

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (Contact cn : contact){
        String log = "Id :"+cn.getId()+" ,Name: "+cn.getName()+" ,Telp: "+cn.getTelp()+" ,Rek: "+cn.getRek();
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        String name = "" + cn.getName();
        HashMap <String, String> contacts = new HashMap<String, String>();

        contacts.put(TAG_NAME, name);
        contactList.add(contacts);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{TAG_NAME}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1});
    listNasabah.setAdapter(adapter);

    listNasabah.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
}}
```

and here's my **databasehelper.java** :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String DB_NAME = "BMIcontact.db";
private static final int DB_VER = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact";
private static final String COL_ID = "id_nasabah";
private static final String COL_NAME = "nama_nasabah";
private static final String COL_TELP = "telp";
private static final String COL_REK = "rekening";
public DatabaseHelper (Context context){
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    //super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "/DataBase/" + File.separator + DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME
            + "TEXT," + COL_TELP + "TELP," + COL_REK + "TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACT_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int NewVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addContact (Contact contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(COL_TELP, contact.getTelp());
    values.put(COL_REK, contact.getRek());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
}
Contact getContact (int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COL_ID, COL_NAME, COL_TELP, COL_REK}, COL_ID + "=?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3));
    return contact;
}

public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setTelp(cursor.getString(2));
            contact.setRek(cursor.getString(3));

            contactList.add(contact);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}

public int getContactsCount(){
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    return cursor.getCount();
}}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @UmaKanth how to stacktrace my project ?

Comment: It's in the LOGCAT tab

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never forgett the spaces between sql keywords and table/column names:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_NAME
            + " TEXT," + COL_TELP + " TEXT," + COL_REK + " TEXT" + ")";


db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME);
```

or do you think this could be executed?

```
CREATE TABLEcontact
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have made a mistake in creating the table where you defined COL_TELP as TELP rather than text as input paramater I think

Comment: i already change "TELP" with "TEXT" but the result still the same

Comment: did u provide the access for read and write in manifest? and also close then cursor once you are done with cursor.If possible post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Change Database version from 1 to 2.